# How can I keep all subcategories in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

When a user adds an ad, he selects the category in which the ad will be located. The category tree consists of 3 branches. The scheme is as follows:

```
parent_category => subCategory => subSubCategory
or
Games => Playstation 5 => Consoles or Discs or Accessoires
```

I use select to output the last element of the category(consoles or discs or accessoires) and write his slug it to the database.

How can I add parent(games) and subCategory(Playstation-5) to the database?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code?

Comment: Please tell us if you one single model for storing the category level or each having a separate table? also, share your controller, route and blade template codes here

Comment: I guess you are hardcoding Games and Playstation 5 and the only one form data is the 'subSubCategory' right? i have some questions, why do you hardcode categories instead of retrieving them from database? My recommendation is to use recursives methods on the Category Model, if you need help just write.

Answer (score 0):

First Of all, you need to make a Tabel so with laravel migration I suggest you run This command

```
php artisan make:model Category -c -m
```

this will make model & controller and migration of your category

and your category tabel can be like this

1. id
2. name
3. super_category_id
4. category_id

now you can run

```
php artisan:migrate
```

now if super_category_id and category_id is Null It's SuperCategory like (Games)

if category_id is null it's Category like (Playstation 5)

and if category_id is not null it's subcategory like (Accessories
)

it's all hope it solve your problem!